# .bashrc does not read environment path correctly with spaces

Tags: android, linux, bash, environment-variables

In my Ubuntu 13 I have edited my .bashrc adding an environment path:

```
export OGRE_ANDROID_ROOT=/home/piperoman/Librerias/Ogre\ Android\ SDK
```

If I *echo* the variable, it works fine, but when I try to use it in a makefile, it does not. I have tested with a `cd` command and this is the result:

```
$ echo $OGRE_ANDROID_ROOT 
/home/piperoman/Librerias/Ogre Android SDK
$ cd $OGRE_ANDROID_ROOT
bash: cd: /home/piperoman/Librerias/Ogre: No such file or directory
```

Why does `echo` work but I cannot use the variable correctly with commands?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short-answer: [Word-splitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html).

When you have this

```bash
export OGRE_ANDROID_ROOT=/home/piperoman/Librerias/Ogre\ Android\ SDK
```

The environmental variable contains "/home/piperoman/Librerias/Ogre Android SDK".

If you use it without enclosing in quotes, Bash will split the string into words based on the `IFS` environment variable – by default tab, space, and newlines.

So

```
cd $OGRE_ANDROID_ROOT
```

is equivalent to

```
cd "/home/piperoman/Librerias/Ogre" "Android" "SDK"
```

So you should quote it, i.e. `"$OGRE_ANDROID_ROOT"`

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
cd "$OGRE_ANDROID_ROOT"
```

with quotation marks.

Comment: @Piperoman, that will work. Have you tried it? `mkdir dir\ with\ spaces; var=dir\ with\ spaces`, then `cd $var` gives `bash: cd: dir: No such file or directory`, but `cd "$var"` is successful

Comment: yes, I have tested it on GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu), however with a different path which also contained spaces.

Comment: The problem was the export: OGRE_ANDROID_ROOT="/home/piperoman/Librerias/Ogre Android SDK" and cd "$OGRE_ANDROID_ROOT" works.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the line in `.bashrc` without the backslash:

```
export OGRE_ANDROID_ROOT="/home/piperoman/Librerias/Ogre Android SDK"
```

and then use quotes to wrap the variable when you want to `cd`:

```
cd "$OGRE_ANDROID_ROOT"
```

Tested with `export MYT="/home/me/test/my test/"`

Answer (score 1):

This is because the folder name as white spaces in between. In linux this whitespaces are normally not used as they are not identified as a single folder.

For example

```
$ mkdir hello\ world                    // will create a folder named hello world
$ cd hello\ world                      // go in to the created folder
$ pwd                                  // display the directory name
```

**this will display as hello>space< world** 
 **Hence the environment vairable $OGRE_ANDROID_ROOT is set as /home/piperoman/Librerias/Ogre and not /home/piperoman/Librerias/Ogre Android SDK**

> To resolve this error rename the folder, so that whitespaces are removed